# C++ Vectors adding and subtracting throwing out "expression: vector subscript out of range." error

Tags: c++, vector

I'm having a tad bit of trouble with my code. I've made a 10x10 grid, in which a player can move around. In this grid are enemies and certain events. I've used a vector to store these events in. For example, if a player hits the tile "e" in the 10x10 grid array, the player would run into an enemy, and the "e" in the vector would be reducted so that wouldn't happen again on that tile, instead, displaying "corridor". This works for the "e" tile (line 147), but when I try to replicate the code for the "i" (line 133) tile, it breaks and comes out with the error "expression: vector subscript out of range.". I have no idea why it's doing this, I'm quite new to coding. If you start the game, and move to X:10 Y4, you will see the error. I'd really appreciate any feedback or advice. Apologies if the code is long as well, I've tried to condense it as much as I can.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int nextX;
int nextY; 
int playerX = 1;
int playerY = 1;

std::string name;
std::string move;

bool win = false;

std::vector<std::string> playerPrivInv;

void movePlayer(int prevX, int prevY);
void location(int X, int Y);
void game();


char dungeon[12][12] = {
{ 'w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w'},
{ 'w','s','c','c','c','c','w','c','c','c','r','w'},
{ 'w','c','w','w','w','c','w','c','w','w','w','w'},
{ 'w','D','w','c','w','c','w','c','w','w','w','w'},
{ 'w','R','w','c','w','c','d','e','c','c','i','w'},
{ 'w','w','w','c','w','c','w','w','w','w','w','w'},
{ 'w','w','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','w','r','w'},
{ 'w','w','c','w','w','w','w','c','w','c','c','w'},
{ 'w','w','c','w','i','c','c','c','c','c','b','w'},
{ 'w','w','w','w','w','w','w','c','w','w','w','w'},
{ 'w','f','c','c','c','c','G','c','w','w','w','w'},
{ 'w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w','w'}

};
int main()
{

    playerPrivInv.push_back("e"); // 0
    playerPrivInv.push_back("x"); // 1
    playerPrivInv.push_back("k"); // 2
    playerPrivInv.push_back("i"); // 3

    game();

}

void game() {

    do {

        location(playerX, playerY);
        movePlayer(playerX, playerY);

    } while (win == false);

}

void movePlayer(int prevX, int prevY) {

    std::cout << "You're coordinates are X: " << prevX << " Y: " << prevY << std::endl;


    std::cin >> move;

    if (move == "n" || move == "north") {
        nextY = playerY - 1;
        if ((nextY >= 0) && (nextY < 12)) {
            playerY = nextY;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Can't move there" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if (move == "e") {
        nextX = playerX + 1;
        if ((nextX >= 0) && (nextX < 12)) {
            playerX = nextX;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Can't move there" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if (move == "w") {
        nextX = playerX - 1;
        if ((nextX >= 0) && (nextX < 12)) {
            playerX = nextX;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Can't move there" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if (move == "s") {
        nextY = playerY + 1;
        if ((nextY >= 0) && (nextY < 12)) {
            playerY = nextY;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Can't move there" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    system("CLS");

}

void location(int X, int Y) {

    char local = dungeon[Y][X];

    // S: Starter Room
    // F: Final Room
    // D: Door
    // C: Corridor
    // R: Room
    // W: Wall
    // E: Enemy
    // X: Enemy
    // K: Enemy

    switch (local) {

    case 'i':

        if (playerPrivInv[3] == "i") {

            playerPrivInv.erase(playerPrivInv.begin() + 3);
            std::cout << "Interogated!" << std::endl;
        }
        else {

            std::cout << "Corridor" << std::endl;
        }

        break;
    case 'r':
        std::cout << "Room" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 'e':

        if (playerPrivInv[0] == "e") {

            playerPrivInv.erase(playerPrivInv.begin() + 0);

            std::cout << "Enemy" << std::endl;

        }
        else {

            std::cout << "Corridor" << std::endl;
        }
        break;
    case 's':
        std::cout << "Starter Room" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 'f':
        std::cout << "Godrik's Finale" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 'd':
        std::cout << "There's a door in the way, its unlocked..." << std::endl;
        break;
    case 'D':

        if (move == "s" || move == "south") {

            nextY = playerY - 1;

            if ((nextY >= 0) && (nextY < 12)) {

                playerY = nextY;
            }

        }

        std::cout << "There's a door in the way, its locked..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "You need to find a key..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        break;
    case 'c':
        std::cout << "Corridor" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 'R':
        std::cout << "You enter a dark office..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Room" << std::endl;
        break;
    case 'w':

        if (move == "e" || move == "east") {

            std::cout << "That's a Wall" << std::endl;
            nextX = playerX - 1;

            if ((nextX >= 0) && (nextX < 12)) {

                playerX = nextX;

            }
        }
        else if (move == "w" || move == "west") {

            std::cout << "That's a Wall" << std::endl;
            nextX = playerX + 1;

            if ((nextX >= 0) && (nextX < 12)) {

                playerX = nextX;

            }
        }
        else if (move == "s" || move == "south") {

            std::cout << "That's a Wall" << std::endl;
            nextY = playerY - 1;

            if ((nextY >= 0) && (nextY < 12)) {

                playerY = nextY;

            }
        }
        else if (move == "n" || move == "north") {

            std::cout << "That's a Wall" << std::endl;
            nextY = playerY + 1;

            if ((nextY >= 0) && (nextY < 12)) {

                playerY = nextY;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you handle the case for `'e'`, you remove one of the elements from `playerPrivInv`, leaving it with 3 elements. Later when you try to process the case for `'i'`, your attempt to access `playerPrivInv[3]` results in the out of bounds runtime error because that vector only has 3 elements in it, not four.

Possible solutions include changing the element in `playerPrivInv` to something else (like an empty string) rather than erasing it from the vector, or searching the vector for the matching string rather than assuming it lies at a particular place.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get it to work by taking away the original vector object and adding another one after that. It changes the numbers around a bit, but it's stopped breaking.